# Converting Excel file (xlsx) into Json

Tags: java, json, excel

I will be reading an `excel` file and convert it into `json` and create `json` file.

**Code:** *(I have tried)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(
            "C:\\Users\\SomeExcel.xlsx"));

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using for-each loop\n");
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Closing the workbook
    workbook.close();
}
```

I am kinda stuck with converting cell content into json key-value pair.

Please check and let me know.

Comment: so what is the question and what has been tried so far

Comment: @Satya , I have tried reading excel and stuck in the locale based file creation.

Comment: can we see some code please

Comment: I suggest to approach this problem with two stages, 1) read the xlsx file into a class structure representing the json, 2) dump the class to a json file, those tasks are fairly simple and the web containing a lot of info

Comment: @shahaf could you please elaborate and suggest me with an example

Comment: You would have an easier time using Xcelite (http://www.xcelite.io/) if you know the structure of your Excel files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the other answers, with that information i have tried and found the solution.

**Code:**

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\SomeExcel.xlsx"));

// Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

// Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

SomePojo somePojo = new SomePojo();

Map<Object, Object> x = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// ignoring header for that I've +1 in loop
for(int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
{

    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for (int j = row.getFirstCellNum(); j <= row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        Cell ce = row.getCell(j);
        if (j == 0) {
            // If you have Header in text It'll throw exception because it won't get
            // NumericValue
            somePojo.setName(ce.getStringCellValue());
        }
        if (j == 1) {
            somePojo.setValue(ce.getStringCellValue());
        }
        // Same for third column
    }
    x.put(somePojo.getName(), somePojo.getValue());
}

// Object to JSON in String
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// Object to JSON in file
mapper.writeValue(new File("C:\\some.json"),x);
// Print in console
String jsonFromMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(x);
file.close();
```

**SomePojo.java**

```
public String name;
public String value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the excel with Apache POI and generate Json using JsonGenerator:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(
    new File("data/output.json"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);

generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeStringField("stringField", "stringValue");
generator.writeNumberField("numericField", 25);
generator.writeEndObject();

generator.close();
```

See: [Oracle Java JSonGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the question it isn't quite clear where you stuck at, I assuming you figured out the reading from excel part, when reading you just need to insert the cell's values to a [Map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) and than dump it to json, I used [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) lib as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    // this should happen in a for loop (reading from the excel file)
    map.put("ABCD", "hello");
    map.put("key1", "value1");

    try {
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: i havent figured out reading logic from excel, as i said i am stuck with logic where first json file has to be created for english then next based on locale